# Time functions in mingw

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, network-programming, mingw

I am trying to implement the code given in this page

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I am using mingw (gcc) to compile this.
But the following lines cannot be compiled. I have included 'time.h'. I searched but cannot locate this '_localtime31_s' or its equivalent in gcc.

```
error = _localtime32_s(&newtime, (__time32_t*) &pAdapter->LeaseObtained);
error = asctime_s(buffer, 32, &newtime);
```

Where is the time functions here?
Thanks

Comment: If this is not code running in threads, then use `localtime`, however that may be "non-reentrant".

Comment: And `asctime(buffer, &newtime)`

Comment: tried and working. The function arguments and return values are different in this case. no error provision.
Any workaround to maintain same program flow?
But why? gcc has no such implementation as '_localtime32_s' or 'asctime_s' ?
Thanks

Comment: I'll explain better in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `localtime_s` and `asctime_s` are Microsoft-specific extensions, provided by (certain versions of) the MS runtime library. This is provided by the MS header files. Since those are copyright MS and not allowed for free distribution, mingw provides its own versions of headers - and these probably don't contain these extensions (they certainly didn't a while back when I was using mingw on my local machine - my main machine these days runs Linux...).

Note that casting the time value to `time32_t *` is probably a bad idea - it is almost certainly going to bite you if you ever compile your code with a `time_t` that isn't a 32-bit value.

The [`localtime_r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/localtime.html) function is a semi-standard version that could be used instead of `localtime_s` (you will need to pay attention to 32 vs 64-bit time values). You can certainly also use `localtime` (aside from having to turn off MS's annoying "this function is not safe, please use `..._s` instead" - I don't *REALLY* want to convert my 100 uses of strcpy to strcpy_s that work perfectly fine because it has already been checked elsewhere).

Similarly there is [`asctime_r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/asctime.html) which provides a re-entrant version.

You could, perhaps, also add the prototypes for these functions to your file somewhere, I believe that would, as long as you are compiling for Windows, solve the problem:

Link to MS function documentation: [`localtime_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [`asctime_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6htak9c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) provides an option to enable the secure CRT functions. Note there are compatibility issues with Windows XP, where msvcrt.dll does not contain these functions and your application will not work in that environment.

These are standardized in [C11 Annex K](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/API02-C.+Functions+that+read+or+write+to+or+from+an+array+should+take+an+argument+to+specify+the+source+or+target+size), which is optional and may be missing on C11 conformant systems.