# localtime_r support on MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I'm working on a Win32 multithread C++ project and I would like to use one of the `localtime_*` thread-safe alternatives to `localtime()`.

Unfortunately I have to use MinGW compiler, and `localtime_s` cannot be used outside Microsoft stuff.

The problem is that neither `localtime_r` is working: the related code snippet is

```
#include <ctime>

...

string getCurrentTime()
{
    time_t t;
    time(&t);
    struct tm timeinfo;
    //localtime_s(&timeinfo, &t);
    localtime_r(&t, &timeinfo);

    char buf[128]; 
    strftime(buf, 128, "%d-%m-%Y %X", &timeinfo);

    return string(buf);
}

...
```

This is the compiler output:

```
error: 'localtime_r' was not declared in this scope
```

Does MinGW support `localtime_r` ?

If not, does exist a thread-safe alternative? (excluding boost/QT/etc that I can't use).

---

EDIT: this is the `<time.h>` provided by my MinGW installation: http://pastebin.com/0CYBfMzg

Comment: What does "`localtime_s` cannot be used outside Microsoft stuff" mean?  MinGW targets msvcrt.dll, and msvcrt.dll does define `localtime_s` (its exported as `_localtime32_s` and `_localtime64_s`, for 32-bit and 64-bit `time_t`, respectively).  If it's not declared by the MinGW library headers, then declare it yourself and call it.  See the Visual C++ library headers for its declaration.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Many sources says that can be used only with microsoft compiler. I have already tried (including `<windows.h>`) and compiling with g++ I get `error: 'localtime_s' was not declared in this scope`. For example see that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085603/time-functions-in-mingw/17088374#17088374

Comment: I don't know what these "many sources" are, but they are wrong.  It's not declared by `<windows.h>`, it's declared by `<time.h>` in the (old) Visual C++ SDK.  If it's not declared by your copy of MinGW's `<time.h>`, you need to declare it yourself.

Comment: Ok, I have posted my `<time.h>` in the question. Indeed `localtime_s` seems missing. How can I declare it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does MinGW support localtime_r ?

No.

> If not, does exist a thread-safe alternative? (excluding boost/QT/etc that I can't use)

mingw will use the native [localtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc.aspx) function on windows, which is thread safe. (But it's not reentrant, so watch out for that).

Comment: Ooooh that's nifty. I didn't catch that in the documentation. The POSIX versions use static globals instead.

Comment: Actually, MinGW does support `localtime_r` now, provided you `#define _POSIX_THREAD_SAFE_FUNCTIONS` before you `#include <time.h>` – see definitions here: https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/v6.0.0/mingw-w64-headers/crt/time.h#L308

Answer (score 4):

My quick solution:

```
#include <time.h>
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#   define localtime_r(T,Tm) (localtime_s(Tm,T) ? NULL : Tm)
#endif
```

(Inspired by MinGW code, search for `_POSIX_THREAD_SAFE_FUNCTIONS`.)

Answer (score -2):

Try using the function `localtime` instead of `localtime_r`:

```
time_t t;
struct tm *timeinfo;
time(&t);
timeinfo = localtime(&t);
printf ("%s", asctime(timeinfo));
```